# Convert a string to the exact same int in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, integer

So, I've got a string containing an offset which like this:

```
Dim myString as String = "&AE6D0"
```

However, for the `BinaryWriter` I need it to be an integer like this:

```
Dim myInt as Integer = &AE6D0
```

How can I convert myString to myInt?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "&" sign from the beginning of the string and then convert it like this:

Dim myInt as Integer = Convert.ToInt32("AE6D0", 16)

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f1cbtwff%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

(I interpreted your offset as being a hexadecimal value, that's why there is the 16)